# Camunda workflow war version

Tags: camunda

Is there a way to get the version of a deployed workflow war via a REST call in Camunda?

I have admin privileges to the application but not the OS on which it is running.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. A war File does not have any version.
You could manually synchronize BPMN Version Tag with your war version.